# Erro ao tentar adicionar sessão no startup

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015, dotnet-cli

Estou com um problema, sempre quando vou compilar a solução esta dando erro:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.ISessionStore' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware'.'

#### Arquivo Startup.cs

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });


    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();
    app.UseSession();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

Comment: Como está o seu arquivo Startup.cs??

Comment: Caro @thiago-corrêa favor ajustar a sua pergunta, ela tem problemas de formatação. Não utilize somente a imagem para mostrar o erro, copie e cole ele na pergunta, assim irá facilitará a pesquisa futura para outros membros.

Comment: Conforme solicitado fiz a alteração.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É como o rapaz acima falou, tente colocar o services.AddSession();

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    // Este trecho aqui
    services.AddSession();

    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Isso ocorre porque você não pode "configurar" a sessão sem antes adiciona-la aos serviços. Para consertar, adicione-o ao método `ConfigureServices` desta forma:

```
services.AddSession();
```

Veja mais na [documentação oficial do aspnet core](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.2).